# Adding words and checking in Arraylist Hangman

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

I'm having trouble with adding words and using do while in my code:

```
ArrayList<String> word = new ArrayList<>();
word.add("fish");
word.add("chicken");
word.add("icecream");
int lengthz = word.size();

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Hangman");
System.out.println("1. 1 Player");
System.out.println("2. 2 Player");
System.out.println("3. Add word");
System.out.println("4. Quit");
System.out.print("Choice : ");
int opsi = sc.nextInt();

if (opsi == 3) {
    boolean show = false;
    boolean founded = false;
    System.out.println("Input the words to be added : ");
    boolean showall = true;

    do {
        String input = sc.next() + sc.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < lengthz; i++) {
            if (!input.equals(word.get(i))) {
                while (!founded) {
                    word.add(input);
                    System.out.println("Succeed!");
                    founded = true;
                }
            } else if (input.equals(word.get(i))) {
                while (!show) {
                    System.out.println("Already Added");
                    show = true;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Want to add more words?");
        String answer = sc.next() + sc.nextLine();
        if (answer.equals("no")) {
            System.out.println("Thanks for adding");
            showall = false;
        } else if (answer.equals("yes")) {
            opsi = 3;
        }
    } while (showall);
    for (int i = 0; i <= lengthz; i++) {
        System.out.println(word.get(i));
    }
}
```

My desired output will be like if the user wants to add more word with "yes" then it will repeat the program, and if the user types "no" then it will display all the words together with the addition, and then going back to show the menu 1-4 option. Please help me ... Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Structure your code, e.g. as follows:

```
static final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
static List<String> words = getStandardWords();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("-- Hangman --");
        System.out.println("1. 1 Player");
        System.out.println("2. 2 Player");
        System.out.println("3. Add word");
        System.out.println("4. Quit");
        System.out.print("Choice : ");
        String choice = in.nextLine();

        switch (choice) {
            case "1":
                //todo
                break;
            case "2":
                //todo
                break;
            case "3":
                addWord();
                break;
            case "4":
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid choice: " + choice);
                break;
        }
    }
}

static List<String> getStandardWords() {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    result.add("fish");
    result.add("chicken");
    result.add("icecream");
    return result;
}

static void addWord() {
    System.out.println("Input the word to be added: ");
    String word = in.nextLine();

    // add word
    if (words.contains(word)) {
        System.out.println("Already Added");
    } else {
        words.add(word);
        System.out.println("Succeed!");
    }

    // add more words?
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Want to add more words?");
        String choice = in.nextLine();

        switch (choice.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT)) {
            case "n":
            case "no":
                System.out.println("Thanks for adding");
                // print all words
                for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println(words.get(i));
                }
                return;
            case "y":
            case "yes":
                addWord();
                return;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid coice: " + choice);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You need to initialize the

```
founded = false;
```

inside do - while loop

2) use last printing for loop as below :

```
 for(int i=0; i<word.size();i++)
 {
     System.out.println(word.get(i));
 }
```